# Record samples being played with OpenAL

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, openal

I am playing 9 loops simultaneously using OpenAL on iOS.  In order for the loops to be 100% synchronized they are started playing on different threads.  Any pointers/tutorials on using OpenAL to record what is being played. Wil I encounter issues recording given I am using different threads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenAL on iOS doesn't support audio recording. You'd need to use audio units to play the audio and route it to both the speakers and a file.

Comment: I'm new to ios and audio programming, i have the same problem, i built a synth using openAL cause i use the pitch shifting included.But i want to record the sound i produce with the synth and maybe send it by email.
Can you explain how to route the audio to a file?
Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, it's very hard to do that in iOS. You can't reroute anything produced by OpenAL or any of the high level audio libraries. So if you want to record to a file, you need to redo everything (including the stuff you did in OpenAL) in Audio Units. Audio Units itself is very low level (OpenAL is written on top of it), so there's no easy way to do this without learning the whole thing. Here's the top link. Good luck. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioUnitProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html