# Can AVAudioRecorder be used to record audio coming from your iOS app?

Tags: ios, audio-recording, avaudiorecorder

I'd like to record the audio coming **from** my iPhone app. So after the background music and sound effects are mixed I'd like to sample the audio before it's played from the device's speakers (or headphones).

I've been experimenting with [RemoteIO Audio Units](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioUnitHostingGuide_iOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009492-CH1-SW1). These seem promising. However they're pretty low level. Can `AVAudioRecorder` (or other "high-level" object) be used to capture audio coming **from** an iOS device?

Comment: I need the same thing.
I have to record the audio coming from my app. I built a synth and i want to record what the user is playing, create a file and upload it on music share platform, a lot of musical apps do it, i'm using OpenAl to play, loop pan and pitch the samples.
I saw that a lot of people are trying to figure out this problem but no one has a right solution with an example.
So, if someone can help us please do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there's no way to do this with AVAudioRecorder. You must use Audio Units.

[Record audio iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493989/record-audio-ios)

[Is there a way to record device audio on the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5670326/is-there-a-way-to-record-device-audio-on-the-iphone)

[Record samples being played with OpenAL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703962/record-samples-being-played-with-openal)

[Offline audio recording on iOS with OpenAL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018136/offline-audio-recording-on-ios-with-openal)