# iOS, AudioUnits record to local URL

Tags: iphone, ios, url, audio, audiounit

In my iPhone application I want to record sounds internally produced by my own application, v.s. recording external sounds captured by the mic. Another way of saying this is that I want to record sound straight off the sound card as it's being played. From there I want to save the new recorded sound file to a specified, local URL. A similar question was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493989/record-audio-ios). I've read a few tutorials and have some code, however there are a few things I need help with. Here is my code:

**header file**

```
OSStatus status;
```

**implementation file**

```
#define kOutputBus 0
#define kInputBus 1

static AudioComponentInstance audioUnit;

static OSStatus recordingCallback(void *inRefCon,
                                  AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags,
                                  const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp,
                                  UInt32 inBusNumber,
                                  UInt32 inNumberFrames,
                                  AudioBufferList *ioData) {

    // TODO: Use inRefCon to access our interface object to do stuff
    // Then, use inNumberFrames to figure out how much data is available, and make
    // that much space available in buffers in an AudioBufferList.

    AudioBufferList *bufferList; // <- Fill this up with buffers (you will want to malloc it, as it's a dynamic-length list)

    // Then:
    // Obtain recorded samples

    OSStatus status;

    status = AudioUnitRender([audioInterface audioUnit],
                             ioActionFlags,
                             inTimeStamp,
                             inBusNumber,
                             inNumberFrames,
                             bufferList);
    checkStatus(status);

    // Now, we have the samples we just read sitting in buffers in bufferList
    DoStuffWithTheRecordedAudio(bufferList);
    return noErr;
}

static OSStatus playbackCallback(void *inRefCon,
                                 AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags,
                                 const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp,
                                 UInt32 inBusNumber,
                                 UInt32 inNumberFrames,
                                 AudioBufferList *ioData) {
    // Notes: ioData contains buffers (may be more than one!)
    // Fill them up as much as you can. Remember to set the size value in each buffer to match how
    // much data is in the buffer.
    return noErr;
}


void initializeInternalAudioRecorder() {
    AudioStreamBasicDescription audioFormat; //this is currently being called as a local variable, try calling it as a golbal variable if it doesnt work
    OSStatus status;
    AudioComponentInstance audioUnit;


    // Describe audio component
    AudioComponentDescription desc;
    desc.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Output;
    desc.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO;
    desc.componentFlags = 0;
    desc.componentFlagsMask = 0;
    desc.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;

    // Get component
    AudioComponent inputComponent = AudioComponentFindNext(NULL, &desc);

    // Get audio units
    status = AudioComponentInstanceNew(inputComponent, &audioUnit);
    checkStatus(status);

    // Enable IO for recording
    UInt32 flag = 1;
    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(audioUnit,
                                  kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO,
                                  kAudioUnitScope_Input,
                                  kInputBus,
                                  &flag,
                                  sizeof(flag));
    checkStatus(status);

    // Enable IO for playback
    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(audioUnit,
                                  kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO,
                                  kAudioUnitScope_Output,
                                  kOutputBus,
                                  &flag,
                                  sizeof(flag));
    checkStatus(status);

    // Describe format
    audioFormat.mSampleRate         = 44100.00;
    audioFormat.mFormatID           = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
    audioFormat.mFormatFlags        = kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked;
    audioFormat.mFramesPerPacket    = 1;
    audioFormat.mChannelsPerFrame   = 1;
    audioFormat.mBitsPerChannel     = 16;
    audioFormat.mBytesPerPacket     = 2;
    audioFormat.mBytesPerFrame      = 2;

    // Apply format
    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(audioUnit,
                                  kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat,
                                  kAudioUnitScope_Output,
                                  kInputBus,
                                  &audioFormat,
                                  sizeof(audioFormat));
    checkStatus(status);
    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(audioUnit,
                                  kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat,
                                  kAudioUnitScope_Input,
                                  kOutputBus,
                                  &audioFormat,
                                  sizeof(audioFormat));
    checkStatus(status);


    // Set input callback
    AURenderCallbackStruct callbackStruct;
    callbackStruct.inputProc = recordingCallback;
    callbackStruct.inputProcRefCon = self;
    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(audioUnit,
                                  kAudioOutputUnitProperty_SetInputCallback,
                                  kAudioUnitScope_Global,
                                  kInputBus,
                                  &callbackStruct,
                                  sizeof(callbackStruct));
    checkStatus(status);

    // Set output callback
    callbackStruct.inputProc = playbackCallback;
    callbackStruct.inputProcRefCon = self;
    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(audioUnit,
                                  kAudioUnitProperty_SetRenderCallback,
                                  kAudioUnitScope_Global,
                                  kOutputBus,
                                  &callbackStruct,
                                  sizeof(callbackStruct));
    checkStatus(status);

    // Disable buffer allocation for the recorder (optional - do this if we want to pass in our own)
    flag = 0;
    status = AudioUnitSetProperty(audioUnit,
                                  kAudioUnitProperty_ShouldAllocateBuffer,
                                  kAudioUnitScope_Output,
                                  kInputBus,
                                  &flag,
                                  sizeof(flag));

    // TODO: Allocate our own buffers if we want

    // Initialise
    status = AudioUnitInitialize(audioUnit);
    checkStatus(status);
}

-(void)startInternalRecorder {
        OSStatus status = AudioOutputUnitStart(audioUnit);
        checkStatus(status);
    }

-(void)stopInternalRecorder {
        OSStatus status = AudioOutputUnitStop(audioUnit);
        checkStatus(status);
        AudioComponentInstanceDispose(audioUnit);
    }
```

Now, I'm getting the following errors in my implementation

- 'audioInterface' undeclared,
- 'self' undeclared,

So my questions are how to fix those errors, and how to specify a URL to save the recorded sound file to.

Here is where I got my code: http://atastypixel.com/blog/using-remoteio-audio-unit/comment-page-6/#comment-6734

I know a lot of my problems have to do with my lack of understanding regarding Audio Units, but I would be very very grateful to anyone who helped out. Thank you.

Comment: Based on a comment of yours below, it sounds like you want to record audio and save it to a local file on the device. It's natural to phrase it this way since that's how the API declares it, but in the case of your question it might be a bit misleading, as it sort of implies you want to save it on a server somewhere. If you do just want to save the file locally, `AVAudioRecorder` is a much simpler way to do it.

Comment: I just want to save the file locally, but the reason I can't use AVAudioRecorder is because it can only record external sounds (e.g. through the microphone.) I want to record internal sounds right off the sound card on the iPhone. For example if someone was listening to something with headphones in. I want the ability to record whatever is being played from the app to their headphones without having to take off the headphones

Comment: Sorry for the confusion

Comment: My bad, I didn't read your question carefully enough.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, the code you have copy/pasted from seems woefully incomplete. I'd be careful with it. :) Also it seems that you have copy/pasted without keeping the structure which it is supposed to have.

Anyways `audioFormat` should be declared as a local variable, it's type is `AudioStreamBasicDescription`. The top part of the code (ie, everything above the `recordingCallback` function declaration) is actually meant to be an initialization function, though the original author wasn't so explicit about this. So that code needs to be wrapped in something like this:

```
void initializeMyStuff() {
  // Describe audio component
  AudioComponentDescription desc;
  desc.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Output;

  ... lots more code ...

  // Initialise
  status = AudioUnitInitialize(audioUnit);
  checkStatus(status);
} // <-- you were missing this end bracket, which caused the compilation errors

static OSStatus recordingCallback(void *inRefCon,
                                  AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags,
                                  const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp, ... etc
```

... and call this when you start the audio portion of your app. If you wrap the first part of this code in a proper C function the nested function error will disappear. As for the undeclared functions, you should either move `recordingCallback` and `playbackCallback` above `initializeMyStuff`, or declare them at the top of the file.

You should also get rid of `-(void)testMethod` and just call the C function `initializeMyStuff()` instead of that. Does this make sense?

Comment: yeah it does makes sense. So then how do I save the audio file I created by recording, to a URL that I specify on disk? I can create the URL, and with the AVAudioRecorder I simply initialize the recorder with the URL I want to save the file too, but it doesnt look like I can do that here...

Comment: So it's still ok if I declare 
    OSStatus status;
    AudioComponentInstance audioUnit;
in the header file, or do I need to declare them at the top of initializeMyStuff()?

Comment: The `audioUnit` might need to be global (in which case it should be declared `extern` in the header and then actually declared at the top of the .c file).

Comment: ok I have updated my code in my question. I declared audioUnit extern in my header file but I dont understand how to actually declare it at the top of the .c file. I'm actually not using a C file. All of my program is in Objective -C with the exception of this part.

Comment: In the header file, you have `extern AudioComponentInstance audioUnit;`, and in the top of the implementation file (I guess it doesn't have to be pure C), you have `AudioComponentInstance audioUnit;`. If that doesn't work, try removing the declaration from the header file and simply having `static AudioComponentInstance audioUnit;` at the top of the implementation file.

Comment: that defiantly brought the errors down but I still have 2 more

Comment: I updated my question. Once those two errors r fixed the only thing left that I dont understand is how to save the recording locally on a device to the URL i specify